# Seed data in code first Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using code-first Entity Framework in my ASP.NET MVC project

I have these tables

User

```
public class User:IBaseEntity
{
    public User()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public string LastName { set; get; }
    public string Company { set; get; }
    public string Address1 { set; get; }
    public string Address2 { set; get; }
    public string City { set; get; }
    public string PostalCode { set; get; }
    public string Country { set; get; }
    public string State { set; get; }
    public bool Active { set; get; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { set; get; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Role

```
public class Role : IBaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool Active { set; get; }
    public DateTime? CreatedOn { set; get; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { set; get; }
}
```

UserRole

```
public class UserRole : IBaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

IBaseEntity

```
public interface IBaseEntity
{
     int ID { get; set; }
}
```

I need seed data `User` with `UserRole`

How can I put `UserRole` in method create `User`?

```
 public void CreateRoles(CMSDbContext context)
 {
     if (context.Roles.Count() == 0)
     {
         List< Role> listRole = new List<Role>()
         {
             new Role()
             {
                 RoleName = "Admin",
                 Active = true,
                 CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
             },
             new Role()
             {
                 RoleName = "User",
                 Active = true,
                 CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
             }
         };
            context.Roles.AddRange(listRole);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void CreateUser(CMSDbContext context)
    {
        if (context.Users.Count() == 0)
        {
            List<User> listUser = new List<User>()
            {
                new User()
                {
                    FirstName = "David",
                    LastName = "Lima",
                    Active = true,
                    Email = "admin@domain.com",
                    Address1 = "New York",
                    Address2 = "Chicago",
                    Company  = "Test",
                    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
                    PostalCode = "123456",
                    State = "Test",
                    City = "test",
                    UserRoles =???
                    Password = CMS.Common.HashMD5.CreateMD5("12356")       
                }
            };

            context.Users.AddRange(listUser);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Please focus on method `CreateUser` have property `UserRole`, not sure what I can put here. I also create some roles in `Role` table (admin, user)

I am getting stuck at this point.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks all

Comment: I put like this

` UserRoles =new List<UserRole>()
                        {
                            new  UserRole() {RoleId = 1,UserId = 1}
                        }`
not sure correct or not

Comment: OK,i solved my problem.Thanks all